# Error handling of the lines where regex doesn't match while reading a file

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to read a log file and match some string in each line. Right now, If the line doesn't have any matching string the program exits with an error because the length of `res == 0` and stops reading lines after. I want the program to continue to read the next lines even if regex doesn't match in between.

```
func analyzeLog(s string) (*time.Time, bool) {

    res := regexp.MustCompile(LogLineRegex).FindAllStringSubmatch(s, 1)

    if len(res) == 0 {
        panic("Not Matching")
    }

    timeString := res[0][1]
    description := res[0][2]

    t, err := time.Parse(TimeFormat, timeString)
    check(err)

    return &t, strings.HasPrefix(description, ErrorTerm)
}
```

```
func readLogFile(offset int64) (*ErrorMetrics, int64, error) {

...
...
...

    for {
        line, _, err := r.ReadLine()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        t, hasError := analyzeLog(string(line))

        if hasError {
            em.Count += 1
        }
    }

...
...
...
}
```

What would be a good way to move ahead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have returned the nil value if the returning array length is zero. Now, the function looks like below.

```
func analyzeLog(s string) (*time.Time, bool) {

    res := regexp.MustCompile(LogLineRegex).FindAllStringSubmatch(s, 1)

    if len(res) == 0 {
        return nil, false
    }

    timeString := res[0][1]
    description := res[0][2]

    t, err := time.Parse(TimeFormat, timeString)
    check(err)

    return &t, strings.HasPrefix(description, ErrorTerm)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don’t panic() and your program won’t exit.
You can use log.Println(err) for example and from there handle more precisely when do you want to log and when do you want to panic().

“ The panic built-in function stops normal execution of the current goroutine. When a function F calls panic, normal execution of F stops immediately. Any functions whose execution was deferred by F are run in the usual way, and then F returns to its caller. To the caller G, the invocation of F then behaves like a call to panic, terminating G's execution and running any deferred functions. This continues until all functions in the executing goroutine have stopped, in reverse order. At that point, the program is terminated with a non-zero exit code. This termination sequence is called panicking and can be controlled by the built-in function recover.”

You can also recover from the error but that would mean you have to recover and start reading your logs from the next line and I don’t think its what you want. You just use panic() in the context where you don’t want panic. Use panic where further execution is not possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where do you want the program to panic? I tried panic when res == 0 and It stills exits. Also, I don't want to reread the file for the next line.

Comment: In the for loop you have panic() which is killing your loop and exit the program. Why do you want to panic if you havent fount a match? Just log this event if you need to and dont panic. Panic only when your software is unable to run further.